# expandpath() ?? can python reach out to an external directory on users comp?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, windows

I have a scores text file (game scores kept here) that gets created on completion of game level.

I am installing users downloads of my game into `C:\Program Files\` folder, but programs folder is not writable.

My Python logic (below) in my game levels creates a text file in the existing installation folder, where my other game blend files are stored.

But when I test the download, no scores saved, because the file installs into Windows `C:\Program Files\` folder (which is of course fine, it's the right place for a game, but I lament).

So I want to get the script below to not just create a `scores.txt` file in the existing folder, but to create it in `documents` (**not** `My Documents/`).

My installer will add a blank folder in `documents` whose name is known, lets call it `blurb\`, then Python does exactly what it did before, but create the folder (and of course fetch/get/load) in `documents\blurb\scores.txt`.

This I assume is where it all happens:

`scores = _loadScoresFromFile("scores.txt")`

```
from bge import logic
import pickle

def _saveScoresToFile(list_scores, string_filepath):

    file = open(string_filepath, "wb")
    pickle.dump(list_scores, file)
    file.close()

def _loadScoresFromFile(string_filepath):

    try:
        file = open(string_filepath, "rb")
    except IOError:
        print("Failed to load scores from {}".format(string_filepath))
        return []

    return pickle.load(file)

scores = _loadScoresFromFile("scores.txt")

def display():

    scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
    writer = scene.objects["Writer"]

    name = logic.globalDict["name"]
    score = logic.globalDict["score"]
    score2 = logic.globalDict["score2"]

    tup_entry = (name, score, score2)
    scores.append(tup_entry)
    scores.sort(key=lambda entry: entry [1])

    new_entry_idx = scores.index(tup_entry)

    for entry, i in zip(scores, range(len(scores))):
        new_writer = scene.addObject("Writer_new", writer)
        new_writer["Text"] = "{:d} - {:s} - {:2}:{:2}".format(i + 1, entry[0], entry[1], entry[2])

        new_writer.worldPosition.y -= 0.105 * i
        new_writer.localScale = writer.localScale

        if i == new_entry_idx:
            new_writer.state = 1

    _saveScoresToFile(scores, "scores.txt")

def setName():

    scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
    name = scene.objects ["Name"]

    logic.globalDict["name"] = name["Text"].strip()

def setScore():

    cont = logic.getCurrentController()
    score = cont.owner

    logic.globalDict["score"] = score["Text"]

def setScore2():

    cont = logic.getCurrentController()
    score = cont.owner

    logic.globalDict["score2"] = score["Text"]
```

Comment: Do you mean the path `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents`? AFAIK this one shows as *My Documents* in the OS (and localized on system of other languages) despite its real folder name, which is always English. And do you want to know how to use Python's `expandpath()` or what is it actually about?

Comment: yes, c:\user\USERNAME\documents

Comment: I know :// means to use the existing directory...Im trying to figure out if blender/python can reach out beyond its own directory to edit the scores file in c:\user\USERNAME\documents of the users computer. Im sure this is all quite clear.

Comment: ok...im using an installer to install my game, the installer instals in c:/programs forlder, this is non writable. The pythin code above is in my blender level file, which works fine when i use it in a user folder. but installed in program files, obviously it cannot be written to. I need the code to reach out  to documents or even appdata where a folder is kept that can contain the scores text when its created and then be written on, so my game has persistent memory for scores!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is able to access the entire file system, except paths that require elevated rights (such as `C:\Program files\` and `C:\Windows\`). It can also access them if you run your it as administrator, but you would usually not want that.

If you want to get the user directory path, use:

```
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")
```

It also works on Windows. Example result: `'C:\\Users\\CoDEmanX'`

Note that the *Documents* folder is not necessarily called like that, if you really want the actual path, you'll need to do this:

```
import ctypes.wintypes
CSIDL_PERSONAL= 5       # My Documents
SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT= 0   # Want current, not default value

buf= ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(ctypes.wintypes.MAX_PATH)
ctypes.windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW(0, CSIDL_PERSONAL, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, buf)

print(buf.value)
```

For me it prints `D:\Dokumente`, because I set it up this way on my system.

Comment: huh? so how do i change the code above to simply access a folder (outside of program files) to create a text file with the users scores in my game. My installer will create the blank file....anyway...Ima go buy a gun to shoot myself

Comment: scores = _loadScoresFromFile("scores.txt") I want to use expandpath so i can tell blender to choose a folder outside the program files folder

Comment: I don't see anything Blender-related here, you just determine any writable path, preferably in the user dir (I discourage to use a fixed path, as nothing is guaranteed, like C:\ being the system drive). Check the official Python docs, StackOverflow or whatever for general IO questions.

Comment: Sorry, yesterday was a bit frustrated with this problem, I added this to my code

Comment: from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~") then this scores = _loadScoresFromFile("/home/scores.txt") but its ignoring the variable home as the designated place, i also tried home +scores.txt with no difference

Comment: You don't use a variable there?! `fp = expanduser("~/jareel_scores.txt")`, then use `fp`as saving/loading path.